# How to programmatically turn on virus scanner?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, wmi

I am building an application in C# using winforms which needs to detect if antivirus and anti-spyware are installed, updated, and enabled.  I have implemented the detection logic via WMI, but I would also like to provide the user with the ability to enable them if they are disabled.

I do not know how to do this from C#.  Any ideas please?

Comment: You should point users to the Action Center.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically from my application.Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

Unless a particular antivirus either

1. Has command line switches
2. Automatically starts when loaded

I don't see how you can do it it.

The other issue is that one program messing with security programs is never a good idea. Aside from a company writing a program to manipulate its own software, that sort of function should only be touched by the operating system.

In other words, do point them to the Action Center instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm using Microsoft Security Essentials and I know the path, I can start it with:

```
string processName = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\msseces.exe";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = processName;
p.Start();
```

Comment: Tudor,do you mean by this opening the antivirus and then lets user turn on it?

Comment: This code will only start the executable of the antivirus in case it is turned off. I don't know about enabled/disabled state inside the actual antivirus.